# mvc: Model.IsValid not working if Iam using Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Iam a beginner in MVC.
If iam using below code then Model.IsValid is not validating the object which in this case is Customer.

```
 public ActionResult Submit()
    {
        Customer custObj = new Customer();
        custObj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["CustomerCode"];
        custObj.CustomerName = Request.Form["CustomerName"];

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Load", obj);
        else
            return View("EnterCustomer");
    }
```

While if Iam passing the Customer object in parameter then Model.IsValid is working perfectly.

```
public ActionResult Submit(Customer obj)
    {
        //Customer custObj = new Customer();
        //custObj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["CustomerCode"];
        //custObj.CustomerName = Request.Form["CustomerName"];

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Load", obj);
        else
            return View("EnterCustomer");
    }
```

Can any1 help me in getting to know the reason.

Comment: By Not working, you mean the view load is not getting returned? what are the data annotations rules on your model and the values passed.

Comment: Your model binding is already happened before reaching to `Sumit` action as it does not accept any parameter that's why ModelState is not validated.

Comment: if you do not have a model then how the validation will work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work beause MVC never bound to the model itself. You manually overrode it so MVC has no clue whether the model is valid or not. It doesn't event know that `custObj` is the model.

`ModelState.IsValid` is set before your action method is called, so in your second example, when you allow MVC to bind to the model itself, it works. In the first, it doesn't work because you create the model and do manual binding to it.

**Update**

You can, however, also manually run the model validation by calling `ValidateModel` or `TryValidateModel` on the controller.

Documentation:

- ValidateModel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.validatemodel(v=vs.100).aspx
- TryValidateModel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the code according to your suggestion and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, your model is already validated before the action 'Submit' is called. So, when you are changing the model from inside your action, you will have to manually validated the model. You may use below code for it.

`var context = new ValidationContext(custObj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(custObj, context, validationResults, true);`

`if (isValid)
   return View("Load", obj);
else
   return View("EnterCustomer");`

use below url for further details. 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx